# Active menu-item in a Express menu

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

Im trying to do a simple menu for an app in Expressjs. I want the class "active" to be set to the menu list item of the page you are currently visiting... 
I have a Jade view file in Express.js with the following code:

```
li(class = path === "/id/admin" ? "active" : "")
  a(href='/id/admin', title='admin') Admin
li(class = path === "/id/admin/services" ? "active" : "")
  a(href='/id/admin/services', title='services') Services
li(class = path === "/id/admin/staff" ? "active" : "")
  a(href='/id/admin/staff', title='staff') Staff
```

This is not going to work because the "id" part of the slug is supposed to be dynamic,  depending on which client is logged in. And another prooblem is that some of the slugs, like "/id/admin/staff", may contain extra slugs at the end, like: "/id/admin/staff/new" or "/id/admin/staff/staff-id/edit".

I'm thinking i need some kind of regular expression to match specific parts of the slug. Like: if the slug contains the phrase "/services" somwhere, then activate that list item in the menu. 
But i dont know how i write this and incorporate in Jade's views.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just wanting to do a simple regex to verify part of the path, a pretty basic one would just be

```
li(class = path.match(/^\/id\/admin$/) ? "active" : "") //string has to end with "admin"
  a(href='/id/admin', title='admin') Admin
li(class = path.match(/^\id\/admin\/services/) ? "active" : "")
  a(href='/id/admin/services', title='services') Services
li(class = path.match(/^\/id\/admin\/staff/) ? "active" : "")
  a(href='/id/admin/staff', title='staff') Staff
```

which would match the admin exactly, and then the other two it would simply look for those patterns at the beginning of the path string.

This is also assuming you are passing the path from Express to the Jade template to render.

Comment: Thanks alot! I just managed to write something similar like this, but you solved the last piece with the $ //string has to end with "admin"

.